# How to align and add space while writing dataframe tocsv in python

Tags: python

Just wanted to add space either side to all cell content in DataFrame and needs to be Right aligned.
[Input Format Each column with Tab Space][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MM7e0.png

[Output Format with Each column needs to be separated with 5 spaces and right aligned][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/unc6B.png

I tried with Str.pad ( its applicable for Strings and prefix applicable only for Headers)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

Look into [numpy.linspace](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html#numpy-linspace) and also see the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29244886/6505847).
You can also manually do this by doing the following, for example:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f: 
    in_lines = f.readlines()
with open(outfile, 'w') as f:
    eight_spaces = '        '
    for line in in_lines:
        split_line = line.split()
        out_line = eight_spaces.join(split_line)
        f.write(out_line + '\n')
```