# How to create multiple spacing CSV from pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a pandas dataframe and want to output a text file separated by different spacing for input to other model. How can I do that?

The sample OUTPUT text file is as follow (each columns in the text file correspond to columns in df):

```
SO HOUREMIS 92  5  1  1 MC12          386.91     389.8     11.45
SO HOUREMIS 92  5  1  1 MC3             0.00       0.1      0.10
SO HOUREMIS 92  5  1  1 MC4             0.00       0.1      0.10
SO HOUREMIS 92  5  1  1 ED1             0.00       0.1      0.10
SO HOUREMIS 92  5  1  1 ED2           322.00     397.4     13.00
SO HOUREMIS 92  5  1  1 HL2            25.55     464.3      7.46
SO HOUREMIS 92  5  1  1 WC1             0.00       0.1      0.10
SO HOUREMIS 92  5  1  1 WC2             0.00       0.1      0.10
SO HOUREMIS 92  5  1  2 MC12          405.35     389.3     11.54
SO HOUREMIS 92  5  1  2 MC3             0.00       0.1      0.10
SO HOUREMIS 92  5  1  2 MC4             0.00       0.1      0.10
SO HOUREMIS 92  5  1  2 ED1             0.00       0.1      0.10
SO HOUREMIS 92  5  1  2 ED2           319.90     396.3     13.00
```

Comment: Sorry. The sample text file is the output I want.

Answer (score 1):

After referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490261/python-pandas-write-dataframe-to-fixed-width-file-to-fwf). I found the solution:

```
fmt = '%0s %+1s %+1s %+2s %+2s %+2s %+6s %+15s'
np.savetxt('test.txt', data.values[0:10], fmt=fmt)
```

I can format each columns and specify how many spacing and the alignment.