# Write pandas dataframe to_csv in columns with trailing zeros

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe of floats and wish to write out to_csv, setting whitespace as the delimeter, and with trailing zeros to pad so it is still readable (i.e with equally spaced columns).

The complicating factor is I also want each column to be rounded to different number of decimals (some need much higher accuracy).

#### To reproduce:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame( [[1.00000, 3.00000, 5.00000],
                    [1.45454, 3.45454, 5.45454]] )

df_rounded = df.round( {0:1, 1:3, 2:5} )
df_rounded.to_csv('out.txt', sep=' ', header=False)
```

#### Current result for out.txt:

```
0 1.0 3.0 5.0
1 1.5 3.455 5.45454
```

#### Desired:

```
0 1.0 3.000 5.00000
1 1.5 3.455 5.45454
```

Comment: DId you try converting the dataframe values to string and then saving it?

Comment: I think you want something like this: [Python Pandas, write DataFrame to fixed-width file (to_fwf?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490261/python-pandas-write-dataframe-to-fixed-width-file-to-fwf)

Comment: Best I've got right now: `print("\n".join([','.join(line.split()) for line in df_rounded.to_string(index=False).splitlines()]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the string representation of the dataframe using `df.to_string()` ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html)). Then simply write this string to a text file.

This method also has `col_space` parameter to further adjust the spacing between columns.

Example:

```py
with open('out.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.writelines(df_rounded.to_string(header=False))
```

Outputs:

```
0  1.0  3.000  5.00000
1  1.5  3.455  5.45454
```

---

There is pandas `df.to_csv(float_format='%.5f')` ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877189/float64-with-pandas-to-csv)) but it applies the formatting to values in all columns. Whereas, in your case, you need different formatting for each column.