# Pandas convert a dataframe to a bed file?

Tags: pandas, export-to-csv, bed

I used pandas.to_csv() to convert a pandas dataframe to a BED file by doing this:

**pd.to_csv('xxx.bed', index=False, sep='\t', header=None)**

I want to know if this can successfully convert a dataframe to a bed file, or I am just exporting the dataframe as a csv file.

Comment: can you provide an example of a few rows?

Answer (score 1):

[Bed files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BED_(file_format)) are following a fixed width format, so `to_csv` wouldn't be useful directly.

You have two options:

1- convert your columns to strings with padding to a fixed width, then export to csv

2- use `tablulate` to export as fixed width (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490261/python-pandas-write-dataframe-to-fixed-width-file-to-fwf) for more details)