# How to write a file in specific format?

Tags: python

Here, i provide an example dataset which include the information of date time and the location.

```
p1=pd.DataFrame([2015,2017,2019], columns=['year'])
p2=pd.DataFrame([6, 9, 10], columns=['month'])
p3=pd.DataFrame([1, 7, 18], columns=['day'])
p4=pd.DataFrame([21, 5, 13], columns=['hpour'])
p5=pd.DataFrame([33, 8, 59], columns=['minute'])
p6=pd.DataFrame([7.16, 38.45, 31.40], columns=['second'])
p7=pd.DataFrame([56.7791, 33.214, 35.458], columns=['lat'])
p8=pd.DataFrame([70.5112, 69.2054, 73.6415], columns=['long'])
p9=pd.DataFrame([15.24, 8.64, 23.17], columns=['dep'])
p10=pd.DataFrame([5.4, 3.0, 6.1], columns=['mag'])
p11=pd.DataFrame([22122,22123, 22124], columns=['id'])
df=pd.concat([p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6,p7, p8, p9, p10, p11], axis=1)
```

I require to write the output in way like

```
2015   06 01 21330716056S7791   70E5112   1524 54              022122
```

**explanation of the above format**:

year(4 space) 2-digit-month (1 space) 2-digit-day (1 space) 2-digit-hour 2-digit-minute 2-digit-second(integer part)3-digit-second(float part) 3-digit-lat (integer part) S 4-digit-lat(float part) (3-space) 2-digit-longitude(integer part) E 4-digit_longitude(float part) 3-space 4-digit-depth (1 space) 2-digit magnitude (15-space) 6-digit-event id

**Here is what i did so far**

```
File=str(p1)+"   "+str(p2)+" "+str(p3) +" "+str(p4)+str(p5))+str(int(p6))+str(float(p6))+ str(int(p7)) "S" +str(float(p7))+ "   " +str(int(p8))+"E"+str(float(p8))+ "   "+str(int(p9))+str(float(p9))+ " "+str(int(p10))+str(float(p10))+"   
            "+str(p11)
```

However, i did not find this as a robust approach for file formatting.

Expected format style:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0R2z.png)

May someone share how i can structure this.

Comment: Show us what you have tried to format the line so far.

Comment: @KlausD. please see the updates.

Comment: Looks like a fixed width format file. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490261/python-pandas-write-dataframe-to-fixed-width-file-to-fwf

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to first convert to string form and then call the string module method provided by pandas to stitch the content together, you can refer to the first few columns of content to modify their own subsequent code, the example is as follows

```
import pandas as pd

p1 = pd.DataFrame([2015, 2017, 2019], columns=['year'])
p2 = pd.DataFrame([6, 9, 10], columns=['month'])
p3 = pd.DataFrame([1, 7, 18], columns=['day'])
p4 = pd.DataFrame([21, 5, 13], columns=['hpour'])
p5 = pd.DataFrame([33, 8, 59], columns=['minute'])
p6 = pd.DataFrame([7.16, 38.45, 31.40], columns=['second'])
p7 = pd.DataFrame([56.7791, 33.214, 35.458], columns=['lat'])
p8 = pd.DataFrame([70.5112, 69.2054, 73.6415], columns=['long'])
p9 = pd.DataFrame([15.24, 8.64, 23.17], columns=['dep'])
p10 = pd.DataFrame([5.4, 3.0, 6.1], columns=['mag'])
p11 = pd.DataFrame([22122, 22123, 22124], columns=['id'])
df = pd.concat([p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11], axis=1)
print(df)

df["month"] = df["month"].astype(str).str.rjust(2, "0")
df["day"] = df["day"].astype(str).str.rjust(2, "0")
print()
df["id1"] = df["hpour"].astype(str).str.rjust(2, "0") + df["minute"].astype(str).str.rjust(2, "0") + \
            df["second"].astype(str).str.replace(".", "").str.rjust(4, "0") + \
            df["lat"].astype(str).str.replace(".", "S").str.rjust(7, "0")
.......

print(df[["year", "month", "day", "id1", "long", "dep", "mag", "id"]])
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for suggestions, in this case i need to be very careful in term of spaces. Is there any other way we can adopt to write each column at different position as per the information of line number. E.g year line 0:4, event id line 50:55 and so on.