# Why use read_fwf in Pandas if I can just use read_csv with a custom separator?

Tags: python, pandas

I don't see the point of [`read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html#pandas.read_fwf) in Pandas. Why would I ever use this instead of [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), which supports custom separators? I tried testing both in terms of speed for a large fixed column width file, and `read_csv` is way faster:

```
data = ("colum1    column2222   column3333   column4\n"
        "id8141    360.242940   149.910199   11950.7\n"
        "id1594    444.953632   166.985655   11788.4\n"
        )

colspecs = [(0, 6), (8, 20), (21, 33), (34, 43)]
data = data * 10000000

with open("big_file.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(data)
```

```
start_time = time.time()
df = pd.read_csv("big_file.txt", header=None, dtype={"colum1": str, "column2222": float, "column3333": float, "column4":float}, sep="\s+")
print(f"--- {time.time() - start_time} seconds ---")
--- 4.0295188426971436 seconds ---
start_time = time.time()
df = pd.read_fwf("big_file.txt", header=None, colspecs=colspecs, 
                 dtype={"colum1": str, "column2222": float, "column3333": float, "column4":float})
print(f"--- {time.time() - start_time} seconds ---")
--- 77.41955280303955 seconds ---
```

Comment: did you check that in the example `read_csv` will produce a DF with just one column instead of 4?

Comment: Also note that in FWF there may not be any separator between fields

Comment: From the documentation I would assume, that `read_fwf` is used for a different kind of data sturcture. fwf is an acronym for "fixed width text file". I assume, that the checking steps of `read_fwf` are more specialized to counting white spaces which might lead to the longer process time.

Comment: @buran sorry I forgot to include `sep = \s+`. Included it now. But yeah I didn't think about the case of no separator, but it seems like that's the only use case

Comment: @MaKaNu right, but then what's the point of it?

Comment: checkout http://documentation.abila.com/MAD_MAIN/Content/MAD/DataFilesCSVFormat.htm for an example of fwf without separator

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7666780/4046632

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that the existence of the [`read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) function in the pandas [API](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/index.html) is for *aesthetic purposes*. The core developers have made this function accessible to us with the understanding that, in certain circumstances, it is the only effective means of properly reading a text file as a DataFrame.

One of the examples that I can see (where `read_fwf` comes in handy) is the (`.txt`) file below :

```
87        foo
     341  5
bar  1
```

Unless you come up with a *magic/regex separator*, [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) can't parse the 3 columns correctly.

```
df = pd.read_fwf("file.txt", widths=[4, 5, 4], names=["A", "B", "C"])

print(df)

     A      B    C
0   87    NaN  foo
1  NaN  341.0  5.0
2  bar    1.0  NaN
```